# Forward rtmp stream with GStreamer

Tags: gstreamer, rtmp, live-streaming

How can I forward a RTMP stream with GStreamer. The following doesn't quite work:

`gst-launch-1.0 rtmpsrc location="rtmp://localhost:1936/myapp/mystream" ! queue !  rtmpsink location="rtmp://localhost:1935/test/live"`

With the following [debug messages](http://pastebin.com/NiZbnpwn).

Then after about 2min:

```
Caught SIGSEGV
Spinning.  Please run 'gdb gst-launch-1.0 21031' to continue debugging, Ctrl-C to quit, or Ctrl-\ to dump core.
```

Comment: not sure with the approach.. but what does it output on debug(use GST_DEBUG=4)?

Comment: Added them @otopolsky

Comment: these are not debug logs.. run it like this: `GST_DEBUG=4 gst-launch-1.0 ....`

Comment: Sorry @otopolsky linked them in a paste bin due to the sheer amount. Couldn't really parse out any problems so far.

Comment: looks like its working fine.. whats the problem then? hm there is some latency "marking pending DISCONT" .. but this is expected

Comment: Nothing happens after a while. I forward it to a ffmpeg endpoint and it doesn't start transcoding, then gstreamer reports a segmentation fault :( @otopolsky

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it works only if you demux and mux again:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtmpsrc location=rtmp://192.168.x.x/live/0 do-timestamp=true ! queue2 ! flvdemux name=demux \
    flvmux name=mux \
    demux.video ! queue ! mux.video \
    demux.audio ! queue ! mux.audio \
    mux.src ! queue ! rtmpsink location='rtmp://192.168.y.y/app'
```

Found it on this page, a great resource for sample pipelines: http://www.francescpinyol.cat/gstreamer.html#gstreamer_from_rtmp